# Typing '«' in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Up to fairly recently (maybe a month ago), I used to be able to type those two characters in VS Code: '«' and '»'; using the key combinations Option+] and Option+Shift+] respectively. Now only the second one comes up.

Why is that? Do I need to change some settings?

For information I am using:
Visual Studio Code Version 1.57.1,
on MacOS Big Sur Version 11.2.3.

Comment: Check your key bindings.

Comment: @matt. I see a list with: Command, Keybinding, When, Source; I presume this is what you are talking about. But I don't see anything with any mapping I would expect (related to the '«' and '»' characters). Or I may be looking the wrong way.